# scroll gradient

Tags: html, css

I am using a div with the following css:

```
     #indexFeeds{
     max-height:600px;
     overflow:scroll;
     }
```

and for Chrome at least there is a gradient on the bottom and right side of this div, that is especially visible if max height has not yet been reached, is there any way to get rid of this?

Comment: may u put your code in jsfiddle and put the link of jsfille.

Comment: here is the link if you just want to view the source code, if you like i can still do jsfiddle in a bit. Http://sunnahspace.com what I am talking about is the middle column, right now its just some lorem ipsum, but it will be dynamic content, as you can see on the bottom it has the gradient on it, like there is a horizontal scroll bar or something, ill make it less than 600px in height so you can see the full effect.